# The base64 hash of my node id is not what I expect

Tags: go, graphql, base64, relay, graphql-go

I am using the `graphql-go` library along with `graphql-go/relay`. I am trying to write some basic tests for my API, and am having some trouble with the base64 encoding mechanism. When I execute a simple query for viewer id, the viewer encoded id is wrong.

I am hardcoding the db call to retrieve the first user with id `1`:

```golang
func TestGetViewer(t *testing.T) {
  // Empty and fill the db for consistency
  prepDb()

  query := `
    query {
      viewer {
        id
      }
    }
  `

  // The schema contains a viewer entry point that returns a userType:
  // userType = graphql.NewObject(graphql.ObjectConfig{
  //    Name:        "User",
  //    Description: "A user",
  //    Fields: graphql.Fields{
  //      "id": relay.GlobalIDField("User", nil),
  //    },
  // })
  schema := gql.NewSchema(db)

  // graphql.Do is called by graphql.Execute. I'm trying to get 
  // closer to what is actually called in order to debug
  result := graphql.Do(graphql.Params{
    Schema:        schema,
    RequestString: query,
  })

  // The return data from our query
  data := result.Data.(map[string]interface{})

  // The relay.GlobalIDField in our schema should be calling this method
  // under the hood, however, as you'll see it returns something different
  id := relay.ToGlobalID("User", "1")

  // prints map[viewer:map[id:VXNlcjo= username:janedoe]]
  // notice the last character of the id
  fmt.Println(data)

  // prints VXNlcjox
  fmt.Println(id)
```

The graphql.Do returns something that is really close, but the last character of the encoded id is different from what is returned by `relay.ToGlobalID`. It instead shows the last character padded with `=`. And when I try to run `relay.FromGlobalID("VXNlcjo=")`, it is able to figure out that its `type` is `User`, but it returns an empty string for `ID`. Whereas, if I replace the `=` with `x`, it returns the correct object.

I'm new to Go, and to these concepts, so any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: `VXNlcjox` is "User:1" when decoded, but "VXNlcjo=" is "User:". Note the missing 1.

Comment: Thanks @BurakSerdar, just noticed this myself. I'm trying to track down why it's passing empty string now. Will post once I figure something out.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a big ol' dummy and neglected to write the json field tags when defining my `User` struct to retrieve data from the db. Single capitalization is okay, but since I capitalize both I and D, it wasn't resolving properly and was passing an empty string for the `id`. Below is corrected:

```
type User struct {
    ID int `json:"id"`
}
```

Rookie mistake! But maybe it can be helpful to others.